# Can not connect with ssh to an ubuntu image in Azure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, ssh

I have a problem with my ubuntu vm.

When I tested my application th ssh authentication worked fine with this image:

- c290a6b031d841e09f2da759bbabe71f__Oracle-Linux-6

After that I tried with ubuntu image:

- b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04-LTS-amd64-server-20140618.1-en-us-30GB

And I get this:

- debug2: bits set: 547/1024 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
- debug2: kex_derive_keys debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 debug1:
- SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug2:
- set_newkeys: mode 0 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: Roaming
- not allowed by server debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug2:
- service_accept: ssh-userauth debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
- debug2: key: /Users/me/vm.pem (0x0), explicit debug1: Authentications
- that can continue: publickey debug3: start over, passed a different
- list publickey debug3: preferred
- publickey,keyboard-interactive,password debug3: authmethod_lookup
- publickey debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
- debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey debug1: Next authentication
- method: publickey debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/vm.pem
- debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA debug3:
- sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA
- 6f:9c:f4:64:03:20:48:4a:bf:3f:62:74:32:61:3b:0b debug2: we sent a
- publickey packet, wait for reply debug1: Authentications that can
- continue: publickey debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
- debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Permission denied (publickey).
I checked with password authentication and the authorized_keys file does not contain the key (But I don't know why).

The very  wierd thing is when I tried to create an instance on Azure UI with the same key then everything works fine.

Any idea why i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the sha thumbprint you're posting to the Azure API is uppercase. This process is handled by cloud-init on Ubuntu and the thumbprint you've posted is saved in **/var/lib/waagent/ovf-env.xml.** Later **DataSourceAzure.py** will try to convert the crt file **/var/lib/waagent/{thumbprint}.crt** to public key, where {thumbprint} comes from ovf-env.xml. But the crt file it is trying to convert is always retrieved with an upper-case name. Check this line in **/var/lib/boot.log**, {thumbprint} will be upper-case:

```
Public cert with thumbprint: {thumbprint} was retrieved.
```