# linux azure vm created using chef asking ssh password while trying to bootstrap even rsa file is given?

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, chef-infra

**code for creating the instance**

```
knife azure server create  --azure-dns-name 'azurelocalinstance' --azure-vm-name 'LinuxInstance' --azure-vm-size Medium -I 03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Jenkins272-Ubuntu1404LTS2016-09-13 --azure-service-location "Southeast Asia" --ssh-user myuser --identity-file D:/ACE_Dev/Keys/AZURE_LINUX_KEYS/azure_linux_id_rsa

Waiting for virtual machine to reach status 'provisioning'.................vm state 'provisioning' reached after 2.87 minutes.

DNS Name: azurelocalinstance.cloudapp.net
VM Name: LinuxInstance
Size: Medium
Azure Source Image: 03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Jenkins272-Ubuntu1404LTS2016-09-13
Azure Service Location: Southeast Asia
Public Ip Address: 13.76.143.3
Private Ip Address: 100.104.98.32
SSH Port: 22
Environment: _default

Waiting for sshd on 13.76.143.3:22done

Connecting to 13.76.143.3
Password: 
Failed to authenticate myuser - trying password auth
Enter your password:
ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user myuser@13.76.143.3@13.76.143.3
```

**Error**
the problem i faced was while trying to bootstrap the ssh authentication fails even though the rsa file is specified

the rsa key is genereated by the following code

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571568/can-not-connect-with-ssh-to-an-ubuntu-image-in-azure?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the SSH key on the Azure side too. Simply providing a private key does nothing if the server is not configured to accept it. Knife automatically falls back to password authentication if the key fails (to mimic the behavior of OpenSSH).

Comment: you mean to add the ssh key inside the provisioned machine inside ~/.ssh/myrsafile

Comment: @abinavraam The public part of the key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Basis of key based authentication already covered by numerous tutorials on the web...

Comment: I solved the issue. The issue was actually having multiple authorization files..the file i mention in the command and the file that exists in the knife.rb file got messed up ..Thanks everybody for your time